# Bug in Python interpreter or am I misunderstanding package import mechanism?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, python-3.7

I have the following source tree:

```
planets/
    earth.py
    mars.py
util.py
main.py
```

With the following code:

planets/earth.py:

```
def moon() -> None:
    print('moon')
```

planets/mars.py:

```
def phobos() -> None:
    print('phobos')
```

util.py:

```
import planets.mars  # yes, just this
```

main.py:

```
import planets.earth
import util

def foobar() -> None:
    planets.mars.phobos()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    foobar()
```

Note that in "main.py", I don't explicitly import "planets.mars".  When I run "main.py", instead of getting an error like I was expecting, I get the output of:

```
phobos
```

It seems to me that because I import "planets.mars" in "util.py" and then I import "util.py" in "main.py", "main.py" can see "planets.mars" and thus I can call "planets.mars.phobos()" from "main.py".

However, when I remove "import planets.earth" from "main.py", I get a "NameError: name 'planets' not defined" exception when I try to run "main.py".  That would seem to indicate that "planets.mars" being transitively imported into "main.py" by being imported into "util.py" isn't whats going on and what's really happening is that there's a bug in my Python interpreter.

Can somebody please shed some light on this mystery for me?  I am using CPython version 3.7.0 on Debian 9.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Importing `planets.earth` adds the `planets` module to `main.py`'s namespace, and inserts `planets` and `planets.earth` into `sys.modules`.

Importing `planets.mars` in `util.py` inserts `planets.mars` into `sys.modules` and makes the name `mars` available as an attribute of `planets`.

When `planets.mars.phobos` is accessed in main.py, `planet.mars` can be accessed via the name `planets` in `main.py`'s namespace.

If the import of `planets.earth` is removed from `main.py`, `planets` is no longer in the module namespace so a `NameError` is raised.

If the import of `util.py` is removed, `mars` is not set as an attribute of `planets` and consequently an `AttributeError` is raised.

This behaviour can be confusing, and is one reason why many packages have an `__init__.py` that imports submodule / subpackages so that they are all available when the package is imported.

Comment: "planets" isn't a module.  It is a package.  "earth.py" and "mars.py" are both modules of this package.

Comment: packages are modules too https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/import.html#packages

Comment: Note, especially, the 3rd paragraph from that link: "It’s important to keep in mind that all packages are modules, but not all modules are packages. Or put another way, packages are just a special kind of module. Specifically, any module that contains a `__path__` attribute is considered a package."

Comment: In the sample code I posted, if I comment out "import util" (but keep "import planets.earth"), "planets.mars.phobos()" is no longer visible to "main.py".  I get "AttributeError: module 'planets' has no attribute 'mars'".

Comment: @ArcadioAlivioSincero I've edited my answer to address the effect of removing the util import